# Adding attendees to Office 365 using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Tags: c#, office365

I am working on windows c# application. I am creating new calendar entries on Office 365 by using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` When I add any attendee to calendar item and save to office 365, invitation to attendee is sent automatically. I dont want to send meeting req to attendees and want only to add them. Is there any way to do that?

```
ObjAppointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(p_calendarProperties.invitees);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To avoid sending meeting request to attendees, specify the "SendToNone" SendInvitationsMode value when saving your appointment.

```
ObjAppointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

See Microsoft documentation:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.sendinvitationsmode(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.sendinvitationsmode%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)