# Office 365 REST API - prevent global attendee updates on new calendar invite

Tags: office365

I'm using the Office 365 Calendar REST API (specifically the ["Update Events"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#UpdateEvents) calls) to add and remove attendees. Would like to add invitees without triggering an update to all attendees.

The docs clearly state:

> "If the user is the organizer, the server sends meeting updates to all attendees."

Great. But how do you disable this behaviour?

The `isOrganizer` flag on [EventResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EventResource) does NOT seem to do anything.

The EWS API has a SendInvitationsMode flag which is basically the behaviour I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708579

Is it possible to disable sending out new invites to every attendee using the REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot disable it. This is on our roadmap to add in the future though.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll keep an eye out for updates. Hopefully not too far off!

Comment: @jason-johnston Any news for this?